# Iron-Router Display Different layoutTemplate for notFoundTemplate?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to show 404 pages notFound template like this:

```
Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
```

My issue is that the `layoutTemplate` for `notFound` is the same as different routes just the body is 404 only {{> yield}} is changing,

```
<template name="layout">
        {{> header}}
        <div id="wrapper">
            {{> sidebar}}
            <div id="main-content">
                {{> yield}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

But I want to display a blank page and not to show my admin inside page which basically only seen after login, So my question is how can I set the `notFoundTemplate` `layoutTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is actually the correct (and expected) behavior.

However, if you really want to alter it, try doing this:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
  if (!this.data()) {
    this.layout("myLayoutForNotFoundPage");
  }
  this.next();
});
```